# Why the databases cannot be found in the linked server

Tags: sql-server

I created a database named AED_exercises in my server, BLACKY\A2006 and want it to be linked with the other server named BLACKY\SQLEXPRESS01.

I already linked the two servers but the server BLACKY\SQLEXPRESS01 does not contain the database the BLACKY\A2006 has.
Both servers are under MSSQL.

May I know what is my problem right here?

Comment: It should show up under linked servers, not databases.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you expect. Are you expecting the `AED_exercises` database to be visible via both the `BLACKY\A2006` and `BLACKY\SQLEXPRESS01` linked server catalogs?

Comment: yes i expected the AED_exercises to be in the both servers

Comment: That isn't how linked servers work. You would need to use 4 part making to reference an object on another server.

Answer (score 0):

A linked server is basically just a connection that allows you to access remote objects that reside on a different server using 4-part names or OLE DB with `OPENQUERY`. A linked server does not actually "link" the servers such that the local and remote databases appear as a unified catalog under the both instances.

Below is a 4-part name example for a query that could be run on your `BLACKY\A2006` instance:

```
SELECT *
FROM [BLACKY\SQLEXPRESS01].[AED_exercises].[dbo].YourTable;
```